# Python decorator which set class variable

Tags: python, class, decorator

I have a code which get list of all functions in `FooBar` and a regular expression the function supports on its parameter message:

```
functionList = []

def notify(RegExpression):
    def _notify(function):
        functionList.append((RegExpression, function))

        return function

    return _notify

class FooBar:
    @notify(".*")
    def everything(self, message):
        pass

        @notify("(\w+):.*")
    def reply(self, message):
        pass

for foo in functionList:
    print("%s => %s" % foo)
```

I would like to do something like that but put the list of functions and their parameters into class as a class variable. It would prevent problems when more classes like `FooBar` exist. Each class should have its own list.

```
def notify(RegExpression):
    # ???

class FooBar:
    functionList = []

    @notify(".*")
    def everything(self, message):
        pass

        @notify("(\w+):.*")
    def reply(self, message):
        pass

for foo in FooBar.functionList:
    print("%s => %s" % foo)
```

What put into `notify()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing this directly with a function decorator is impossible, since you would need to access the class which is currently being defined, and this class does not exist yet.  One solution would be to make the decorator just store the regex as an attribute of the method and have functionality collecting these methods on a base class:

```
def notify(regex):
    def decorate(func):
        func.regex = regex
        return func
    return decorate

class Baz(object):
    @property
    def function_list(self):
        for attr in dir(self):
            obj = getattr(self, attr)
            if callable(obj) and hasattr(obj, "regex"):
                yield obj

class FooBar(Baz):
    @notify(".*")
    def everything(self, message):
        pass

    @notify("(\w+):.*")
    def reply(self, message):
        pass

for foo in FooBar().function_list:
    print("%s => %s" % (foo.regex, foo))
```

Comment: Heh, we both posted similar solutions just seconds apart. The property is a nice idea, I didn't think of that.

Comment: @Jochen: Well, except for the timing that's not that much of a coincidence.  There are basically three options to do this: via a base class, via a class decorator or via metaclasses.  Our solutions reflect the two easiest options out of those three :)

Comment: I had no idea it was possible to set properties on methods like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When `notify` is called the class `Foobar` does not even exist yet. Therefore, you can't do with just the decorator.

What you can do is mark the functions with a decorator and collect them after the class has been defined. You can do it with a metaclass or with a class decorator like this:

```
import inspect
def notify(regex):
    def mark( func ):
        func.regex = regex
        return func
    return mark

def collect( cls ):
    cls.functionList=[]
    for name, func in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
        if hasattr(func, 'regex'):
            cls.functionList.append(func)
    return cls

@collect
class FooBar(object):

    @notify(".*")
    def everything(self, message):
        pass

    @notify("(\w+):.*")
    def reply(self, message):
        pass

for foo in FooBar.functionList:
     print("%s => %s" % (foo.regex, foo))
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote it anyways so I might was well just post the third option. It's using a metaclass to collect the functions:

```
def notify(regex):
    def mark( func ):
        func.regex = regex
        return func
    return mark

class RegexBase(object):
    class __metaclass__(type):
        """ creates a list of functions with a `regex` attribute 
            and stores it on the class as `functionList`
        """
        def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr):
            fl = []
            for obj in attr.itervalues():
                    if hasattr(obj, 'regex'):
                        fl.append(obj)
            attr['functionList'] = fl
            return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)


class FooBar(RegexBase):

    @notify(".*")
    def everything(self, message):
        pass

    @notify("(\w+):.*")
    def reply(self, message):
        pass

for foo in FooBar.functionList:
     print("%s => %s" % (foo.regex, foo))
```

I guess it's nice to have all the options together in one thread.

Comment: So that's the third option.  Nice! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's [Jochen Ritzel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343780/390897) answer updated for Python 3.

```
def notify(regex):
    def mark( func ):
        func.regex = regex
        return func
    return mark


class Meta(type):
    """ creates a list of functions with a `regex` attribute 
        and stores it on the class as `functionList`
    """
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        fl = []
        for obj in attr.values():
                if hasattr(obj, 'regex'):
                    fl.append(obj)
        attr['functionList'] = fl
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)

class RegexBase(object, metaclass=Meta):
  pass


class FooBar(RegexBase):
    @notify(".*")
    def everything(self, message):
        pass

    @notify("(\w+):.*")
    def reply(self, message):
        pass


for foo in FooBar.functionList:
     print("%s => %s" % (foo.regex, foo))
```